# When changing the route in angular I must reload the page so that firebase updates my data

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm using this service to get data from firebase, but when I change the route in angle 7, I have to reload the page so that the data appears, know what problem I have?

```
    constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {

this.itemsCollection = afs.collection<Item>('items');
this.items = this.itemsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(actions => actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Item;
    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
    return { id, ...data };
  }))
);
}
```